# Should I Use uWSGI?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am a newbie to web development. My web application is Django + Nginx. My friend suggested using uWSGI too in case the traffic increases and uWSGI will be able to handle that so the website would not become extra slow. But from what I read, it is Nginx that handles high traffic. So which one?

Comment: You don't really have a choice - you need a wsgi/asgi server to run Django in production. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/ .

Comment: You need both nginx + wsgi/asgi based interface in deployment, I highly recommend watching [WSGI for developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqrCnVAkLIo&list=LL&index=2&ab_channel=PyConCanada) to understand the concenpts